# how to use one controller method in another controller in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have two controllers PrivacypolicyController and OtpController in OtpController one method generateotp is there i want use it in PrivacyPolicyController, i am using trait but i am getting error. this is my code.

```
class PrivacyPolicyController extends Controller {
use OtpController;
public function getCheck($phno,$app_type)
{
$authentication =   authentication::select('pp_version','toc_version')
->where('phone_no',$phno  and 'application_type',$app_type);
if ( !$authentication->count() )
{
$this->generateotp($phno,$app_type);
}
}
```

and my otpController is like this

```
class OtpController extends Controller {
trait OtpController{
public function generateotp($number,$length) 
{
for ($c = 0; $c < $length - 1; $c++) 
{
array_push($rand, mt_rand(0, 9));
shuffle($rand);
}
return implode('', $rand);
}
}
```

and the error is 
syntax error, unexpected 'trait' (T_TRAIT), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Answer (score 0):

Your trait should be a complete different file. 
You can also check the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) about traits to learn more about how to create a trait and where `use` it.

After you extract it as a file you can simply type:

Trait:

```
trait OtpController {

    public function generateOtp($number, $length) 
    {
        for ($c = 0; $c < $length - 1; $c++) 
        {
            array_push($rand, mt_rand(0, 9));
            shuffle($rand);
        }
        return implode('', $rand);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class OtpController extends Controller {

    use OtpControllerTrait;

    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using traits, you can simply extend the Controller whose method you want to use in your Controller.